# Reading CSS height/width value are Xpx in FF while 'auto' in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer

Div box dimensions are measured using jQuery with following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var h = $("#testbox").css("height");
});
```

In FF it gives for me 270px, in IE auto. How can I measure actual div height/width in IE without changing it's css?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use .height() and .width().

```
var h = $("#testbox").height();
var w = $("#testbox").width();
```

Answer (score 1):

try putting the css for # testbox

```
#testbox {
   height: 0px; 
}
```

Comment: No.
One of the question parts was: How can I measure actual div height/width in IE without changing it's css?